# "Run Process open . {filepath}" in robotframework is not working on Mac but "Run Process explorer.exe {filepath} is working on Windows

Tags: macos, robotframework

I'm using Robotframework 3.0 on Windows10 and Mac Sierra/El Capitan. I tried to use the "Copy file" from the OperatingSystem Library of RF on both the systems but on Mac it is not working. Here is the script on Mac:

```
Copy file    Testfiles${/}${file}    ${MyDir}
List Directory    ${MyDir}
Run Process open .  /select,${MyDir}${/}${file}  //open . opens the finder
Sleep   5   
Press Ctrl  NUMPAD5    //Right click on Mac
Sleep   1   
Send Keys   e
```

I get the following error:

> OSError: Cannot run program "open ." (in directory "/Users/rj/PycharmProjects/automation"): error=2, No such file or directory

Script on Windows which works:

```
Copy file   Testfiles${/}${file}    ${MyDir}
List Directory  ${MyDir}    
Run Process explorer.exe    /select,${MyDir}${/}${file}
Sleep   5   
Press Alt and Function    10  //Right click on Windows  
Sleep   1   
Send Keys   e
```

Where: Testfiles is a directory and I want to copy the {file} to other directory {MyDir}. Send keys, "Press Alt and Function 10" are the keywords created on my Java library

The RF opens up the Testfiles directory but doesn't select the "file" to copy. This scenario happens only in Mac and the same scripts works perfectly on Windows.

PS: I've changed the path of {MyDir} according to Windows and Mac.

Comment: What does "not working" and "doesn't select" mean, exactly? Why do you think `Copy file` "selects" a file?  Are you getting any log messages, any errors?

Comment: Not working means it actually doesn't do anything, It opens the directory "Testfiles" and stays for 30sec and there is a timeout. I think `Copy file`  selects a file because when I run it on Windows I see the file selection but not on Mac

Comment: How is a file "selected" when you're moving a file? "selected" implies you've opened a window and highlighted a file. Also, when robot times out, what is the error or log message that you get?

Comment: My bad. Copy file was working, I verified the report and got the stupid mistake. The problem was in this piece of script `Run Process explorer.exe /select,${MyDir}${/}${file}` on windows is opening the file but I replaced this script on Mac with `Run Process   open .    /select,${MyDir}${/}${file}`. On Mac, it throws error that cannot run "open ." If I use "Run" instead of "Run Process" then it works but I am not able to see the directory as I have to do a right click after. Is there any way I can open the directory? In windows with the above cmd it opens the directory but not on Mac.

Comment: Your title still says the problem is with `Copy File`.  You need to edit the question and title so that it's clear that the problem is with running the "open" command, and not with the actual copying of the file.

Comment: Also, what is the actual point of opening the file in finder during a test? Are you just trying to verify it was copied? There are better ways to do that.

Comment: _"On Mac, it throws error that cannot run "open ."_ -- what is the exact error message?

Comment: I'm getting an error : `OSError: Cannot run program "open ." (in directory "/Users/rj/PycharmProjects/automation"): error=2, No such file or directory` - This path is the path to my Pycharm workspace. I am expecting the directory should open with the path ${MyDir}${/}${file}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message (as reported in the comments) is telling you exactly what is wrong. I'll highlight the important part:

> OSError: Cannot run program **"open ."** (in directory "/Users/rj/PycharmProjects/automation"): error=2, No such file or directory

Notice that it is telling you it is trying to run a program named `open .` ("open", followed by a single space and a period). Robot keywords in the space-separated format need two or more spaces between arguments. Since `"."` is an argument, you need two spaces between `"open"` and 
"."`:

```
Run Process open  .  /select,${MyDir}${/}${file}  //open . opens the finder
#               ^^ two spaces here
```